# NavigationLink for iOS15 and iOS16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am developing an app that has iOS 15 as minimum target, which meant that it also need to support newer version of iOS.
For screen navigation I'm using NavigationView + NavigationLink (destination:isActive:label:). I need exactly this version of NavigationLink.init because Now, I need to use this specific version of NavigationLink.init because I need it to make the navigation depend on a binding(isActive) but this initialiser is deprecated from iOS16.

When I compile the project I get a warning saying: "init(destination:isActive:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView".

So the suggestion is not useful for me because I would lose the possibility to use the isActive binding in the NavigationLink initiliazation

So my question is what would it be a good strategy for supporting navigation in my app without duplicating a lot of code.
Has anybody come across with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Like any deprecated feature, if you want to support the deprecated version for the benefit of older iOS versions but also use the replacement version in newer iOS versions then you will need to implement both independently and switch using `if #available`.

In this case, it is certainly not trivial to find a way of avoiding a lot of code duplication. But it is possible. I would suggest the following approach:

1. Familiarize yourself with `NavigationStack`. Apple's documentation on [migrating to new navigation types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types) is useful for this.
2. Create an enum to use for identifying the different navigation destinations.
3. Re-factor your links into a separate menu view.
4. Re-factor the parent container so as to support both `NavigationMenu` (for backwards compatibility) and `NavigationStack` (for iOS 16 and above).

Below is a working example to show how it can be done. The first menu item can also be navigated to programmatically and there is an additional button which demonstrates this. Tested with simulators running iOS 14.5, 15.5 and 16.4.

```swift
import SwiftUI

/// An enum to describe the possible navigation destinations
enum MyNavDestination {
    case viewOne
    case viewTwo
}

/// A dummy destination view
struct ViewOne: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View One")
    }
}

/// Another dummy destination view
struct ViewTwo: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View Two")
    }
}

/// The menu containing the navigation links
struct MyNavMenu: View {

    /// Binding to be used for controlling the state of the link to ViewOne
    @Binding private var isViewOneActive: Bool

    /// The menu must be supplied with everything it needs to build the links
    init(isViewOneActive: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._isViewOneActive = isViewOneActive
    }

    /// - Returns the View associated with the first menu item
    private func launchViewOne() -> some View {
        ViewOne()
    }

    /// - Returns the View associated with the second menu item
    private func launchViewTwo() -> some View {
        ViewTwo()
    }

    /// Factory method for a navigation link, for use as a menu item
    @ViewBuilder
    private func createMenuItem<Content: View>(
        navDestination: MyNavDestination,
        label: String,
        activeBinding: Binding<Bool>? = nil,
        destination: () -> Content
    ) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {

            // iOS 16: all links are associated with an enum, so
            // programmatic navigation is possible with all links
            NavigationLink(value: navDestination) {
                Text(LocalizedStringKey(label))
            }
        } else if let activeBinding {

            // Pre iOS 16: a link which is associated with a Binding,
            // allowing programmatic navigation
            NavigationLink(
                isActive: activeBinding,
                destination: destination
            ) {
                Text(LocalizedStringKey(label))
            }
        } else {

            // Pre iOS 16: a link which is not associated with a Binding
            NavigationLink(destination: destination) {
                Text(LocalizedStringKey(label))
            }
        }
    }

    /// - Returns the NavigationLink for ViewOne
    private var viewOneMenuItem: some View {
        createMenuItem(
            navDestination: .viewOne,
            label: "View One",
            activeBinding: $isViewOneActive,
            destination: launchViewOne
        )
    }

    /// - Returns the NavigationLink for ViewTwo
    private var viewTwoMenuItem: some View {
        createMenuItem(
            navDestination: .viewTwo,
            label: "View Two",
            destination: launchViewTwo
        )
    }

    /// - Returns all menu items in a vertical stack
    private var menuItems: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            viewOneMenuItem
            viewTwoMenuItem
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            menuItems
                .navigationDestination(for: MyNavDestination.self) { navDestination in
                    switch navDestination {
                    case .viewOne: launchViewOne()
                    case .viewTwo: launchViewTwo()
                    }
                }
        } else {

            // Pre iOS 16, the destinations are defined with the links
            menuItems
        }
    }
}

/// The parent container
struct ContentView: View {

    /// State variable for controlling the state of the link to ViewOne
    @State private var isViewOneActive = false

    /// The array representing the navigation stack for iOS 16 and above
    @State private var navPath = [MyNavDestination]()

    /// Activates the navigation link to ViewOne
    private func goToViewOne() {

        // Update the relevant state property
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            navPath.append(.viewOne)
        } else {
            isViewOneActive = true
        }
    }

    /// - Returns the menu containing the navigation destinations
    private var menu: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text("MyNavMenu")
            MyNavMenu(isViewOneActive: $isViewOneActive)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(
            Color.black
                .opacity(0.1)
                .cornerRadius(10)
        )
    }

    /// The main content of the body
    private var mainContent: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            menu
            Spacer()
            Button("Go to View One", action: goToViewOne)
            Spacer()
        }
    }

    /// - Returns the main content, wrapped as a navigation view
    @ViewBuilder
    private var navigableContent: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
                mainContent
                    .navigationTitle("")
                    .toolbar(.hidden)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
        } else {

            // NavigationView is deprecated in iOS 16.0
            NavigationView {
                mainContent
                    .navigationBarTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            }
            // Fix for iPad
            .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        navigableContent
    }
}
```

A couple of other notes:

1. As you can see, code duplication is avoided by fragmenting the code into small functions and computed properties. Only the calls to the fragments need to be duplicated for the old and new implementations.
2. It is interesting to note that the `.navigationDestination` modifier is applied to a View inside the `NavigationStack`, not to the `NavigationStack` itself. This is what makes it possible to factor out the menu into a separate View, because all the knowledge about how to launch a target View can be contained in one place.