# How to dismiss a sheet, then go to another view?

Tags: ios, swiftui

My goal are:

1. to dismiss a sheet, the button is in the sheet, then go to another view.
2. when user navigate back, the sheet should pop up again.

What I've tried:

1. I am thinking to use `NavigationLink(titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, destination: View, isActive: Binding<Bool>)` but it's deprecated.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = true
    @State private var selection: PresentationDetent = .medium
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("hello")
                
                // navigate to this
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("hello world")
                } label: {
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            VStack {
                Text("world")
                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large], selection: $selection)
                    .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
                    .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
                
                Button {
                    isPresented = false
                } label: {
                    Text("start")
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current solution: Not sure if this follow Apple HIG or not.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isPresented = true
    @State private var selection: PresentationDetent = .medium
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("hello")
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                VStack {
                    Text("world")
                        .presentationDetents([.medium, .large], selection: $selection)
                        .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
                        .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)
                    
                    Button {
                        isPresented = false
                    } label: {
                        Text("start")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: Binding(
                get: { !isPresented },
                set: { isPresented = !$0 }
            ), destination: {
                Text("hello world")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So `NavigationView` is deprecated too, you want to think about moving to `NavigationStack`. For more on this, see [NavigationLink for iOS15 and iOS16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75838365).

The version below only has one navigation destination, like you had it. But the framework is in place if you wanted to add more (just add more enum cases and more navigation links).

> 1. to dismiss a sheet, the button is in the sheet, then go to another view.

Navigating programmatically to the target view is done by appending the appropriate enum to the navigation path. This is done in the `.onDisappear` callback on the sheet content. You could also do it inside the button callback, but the animation is good if the sheet is dismissed first.

> 2. when user navigate back, the sheet should pop up again.

This is done by setting the `isPresented` flag inside an `.onDisappear` callback on the target view.

```swift
enum MyNavDestination {
    case helloWorld
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var navPath = [MyNavDestination]()
    @State private var isPresented = true
    @State private var selection: PresentationDetent = .medium

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navPath) {
            VStack {
                Text("hello")

                // navigate to this
                NavigationLink(value: MyNavDestination.helloWorld) {
                    Text("hello world")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: MyNavDestination.self) { navDestination in
                switch navDestination {
                case .helloWorld:
                    Text("hello world")
                        .onDisappear { isPresented = true }
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            VStack {
                Text("world")
                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large], selection: $selection)
                    .interactiveDismissDisabled(true)
                    .presentationDragIndicator(.hidden)

                Button {
                    isPresented = false
                } label: {
                    Text("start")
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                navPath.append(.helloWorld)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```