# List selection and detail view on appear - not consistent in iPad

Tags: swiftui

This code works well in iPhone but not on iPad. In iPad, although the "Selected topic" text in TopicDetailView changes with every list selection, onAppear is not getting called. I need to do some backend operation on onAppear here. What am I doing wrong here?

```
import SwiftUI
 
var topics = ["Topic1","Topic2","Topic3"]
struct TopicsView: View {
    var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
           List(topics, id:\.self ) { topic in
                       NavigationLink(
                           destination: TopicDetailView(topic: topic)
                         ) {
                           Text(topic)
                       }
                   }
               }
   }
}


struct TopicDetailView: View {
    var topic: String = "Topic1"
  
    var body: some View  //body{
   {
       VStack{
           Text("Selected topic \(topic)")
        }
        .onAppear(){
           print("on appear on topic \(topic)")
       } 
   }
}


struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
       TopicsView()
   }
   
   
}
```

Comment: Could not replicate your problem. All works well for me in my tests,
  `.onAppear` is always called. On MacOS 14,
  Xcode 15, tested on real ios17 iPad (not Previews).
  It could be different on older systems.
  
  Best if you put `var topics = ["Topic1","Topic2","Topic3"]` inside `TopicsView` and
  use `var topic: String` in `TopicDetailView`. 
  Note `NavigationView` is deprecated, consider `NavigationStack` instead or `NavigationSplitView`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am getting this in latest devices and simulators. In the beginning if you go sequentially, it works well. But if you go backwards and random selections on appear is not getting called. Here is my print. You can see some topics skipped (I just went forward backward in sequence)

Comment: Topic1,
Topic2,
Topic3,
Topic1,
Topic2,
Topic3,
Topic1,
Topic2,
Topic3,
Topic1,
Topic1,
Topic3,
Topic2,
Topic1,
Topic3,
Topic1,
Topic3,
Topic1,
Topic2,
Topic3,
Topic1

Comment: I cannot use NavigationStack or SplitView as I need to support iOS 15.0 onwards

Comment: I can now replicate your issue on iPad ios17 going backwards and random selections. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Agree that it looks inconsistent when the navigation uses column view style.

It appears to work better with stack view style, if that would be an option:

```swift
NavigationView {
    // as before
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

You would only have to do it this way for iOS 15, for iOS 16+ you could use newer navigation techniques (see [NavigationLink for iOS15 and iOS16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75838365/20386264) for an example).